# 500 Server Error AWS Elastic beanstak

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hello Im having an issue with the website I am creating for a project. Everytime I upload it to aws elastic beanstalk it works except when I use a form.

```
<form action="supply.php" method="POST">
Product Name: <input type="text" name="p_name"><br>
Order Qty: <input type="text" name="ord_qty"><br>
Name: <input type="text" name="user_name"><br>
Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset">
</form>
```

this is my form and here is my supply.php where I get the 500 error

```
<html>
<body>

 <h1>Thank you for your order. <? php echo $_POST["user_name"]; ?><br></h1>
  <form action="order.php">
     <input type="submit" value="Go to Orders">
  </form>
<?php
 $p_name = $_POST['p_name'];
 $ord_qty = $_POST['ord_qty'];
 $name = $_POST['user_name'];
 $address = $_POST['address'];
 $string = $p_name. "," . $ord_qty. "," . $name. "," . $address;
 $file = "order.txt";
 file_put_contents($file,$string . "/n", FILE_APPEND);
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Is there something wrong? I can't see any issues and its driving me crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<? php echo $_POST["user_name"]; ?>
```

You have a space in the first opening php tag

Try:

```
<?php echo $_POST["user_name"]; ?>
```

This was enough to break a simple test page I set up, let me know if you're still experiencing problems.

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project, make sure you accept the answer :)